# Accessing file in subdirectory without using forward-slash

Tags: php, linux

I have an issue where I have to read a file, but I can't use the slash character in the path name, as the path name gets split by the slash and only the last part is read. Though I assume there's nothing I can do, I was wondering if anyone here knew of any obscure Linux tricks that would help me accomplish that. FWIW it's a PHP script which splits a file path by '/' and `include`s the last part.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Change the php script so it doesn't split on / ?